# I cannot upgrade a project to .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-framework-version

I'm currently upgrading our solution to the latest.NET Framework 4.8. I have one project that I cannot change.

I can select it through

> Project Properties -> Target Framework

When re-opening the project properties it still shows the old 4.5.2 when checking the TargetFramework version in the project file it shows 4.8, but when building the application it still thinks it's 4.5.2. Also tried to manually set it in the project with the same result.

I have other projects that I could change to 4.8 without any issues.

Comment: what error it showing?

Comment: Just check what happens to the project's .csproj file.  Verify that its content changes when you use File > Save All after you made the change, expectation is that the TargetFrameworkVersion element gets updated.  Look at the file with a simple text editor, Notepad will do fine.  If something evil changes that file back then consider to make the file read-only, with the hope you now get an error message.  Beware of source control.

Comment: Fixed it, needed to change all my 40 projects to 4.8 and then there were no problems anymore

Comment: Hello Maurice, I wanted to upgrade my web application currently at .net framework 4.6.1 to 4.8 , Can you please advise if there was any issue that you faced while doing your upgradation . Or anything else that should be kept in mind before deploying this upgrade.

Comment: You may need to determine which project is dependent on the other and upgrade them in the dependency order. For me, I had to manually change the .csproj file, by finding the ```TargetFramework``` value from v4.5 to v4.8, and i was then able to open it up without any issues. And it showed the same value in the properties tab as well.